# Passing an number input into a function. Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to pass number inputs into a function and get an answer. Here is what I have so far.

```js
var x = firstProblem();

function firstProblem(firstNumber, secondNumber) {
  return firstNumber * secondNumber;
}

document.getElementById("first").innerHTML = x;
```

```css
#firstNumber {
  height: 3em;
  font-size: 2em;
}

#secondNumber {
  height: 3em;
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<p>If I save <input type="number" id="firstNumber" value="0"> a week how many weeks would It take to get to <input type="number" id="secondNumber" value="0"></p>




<p id="first"></p>
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp

Comment: so reference the input values onchange of the inputs.

Comment: Use change events

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const first = document.getElementById('first');
const firstNumber = document.getElementById('firstNumber');
const secondNumber = document.getElementById('secondNumber');

firstNumber.addEventListener('change', onChange);
secondNumber.addEventListener('change', onChange);

function onChange() {
  first.innerHTML = firstProblem(firstNumber.value, secondNumber.value);
}

function firstProblem(firstNumber, secondNumber) {
  return firstNumber * secondNumber;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback.